# What does "note" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> It seemed a romantic business to be a successful literary man—you were not ever going to be as famous as a movie star but what **note** you had was probably longer-lived

from F.Scott Fitzgerald, The Crack-Up

Answer (score 2):

Note here is a synonym for reputation.

[Note](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/note) (MW) - Noun definition 4:

> Distinction, Reputation - a figure of international note.